# How to get related product id / product from course id learn dash plugin wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, learndash

I need to display a product category name and image based on user enrolled course. For that I have user's enrolled course id

`$courses = learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses( $user_id, array(), true );`

Now based on course id I will need to get product id. But I am not getting it. Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks in advance.